# Change WooCommerce [product] style

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to customize my [product id='*'] shortcode from WooCommerce. I want to change a couple of things, the first would be to change the size of this  to 45px instead of 60px:

[Inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIRer.jpg)

I made this design this way:

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwPdZ.png)

The site: http://www.afreenuts.com/shop/

Hope you guys can help me out! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess, it's a design issue. You can change it checking the exact file.

Comment: Which file exactly?

Comment: Check the css file location in the browser's inspect element feature or use !Important in `CSS` to override.